# c++ Segmentation fault printing an unsigned char

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, buffer

I'm getting Segmentation Fault when trying to print a buffer that was filled up by a function:

```
    int ret = 0;
    unsigned char plaintext;

    /* ret will contain the length of the "plaintext" output buffer */
    ret = gcm_decrypt( &ciphertext[0], ciphertext_len, &aad[0], aad_len, &tag[0], (unsigned char*)decoded_key.c_str(), &iv[0], iv_len, &plaintext );

    /* This will segfault BUT it actually prints out the correct data */
    std::string sName(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&plaintext)
    cout << "ret: " << ret << endl;
    cout << "plaintext: " << sName << endl;
```

I've tried many things to get a std::string from that plaintext buffer, but i can't figure it out.

the function requires an `unsigned char *`

```
int gcm_decrypt(unsigned char *ciphertext, int ciphertext_len, unsigned char *aad, int aad_len, unsigned char *tag, unsigned char *key, unsigned char *iv, int iv_len, unsigned char *plaintext)
```

Comment: This expression &plaintext does not point to a string or a character array.

Comment: You are telling the compiler to trust you `plaintext` is a c string (null terminated array of char). When it is instead a single char.

Comment: How about `unsigned char plaintext[somesize];` and make `ciphertext_len=somesize`

Comment: `plaintext` does not have enough memory allocated to it to receive all of the decrypted data. A single `unsigned char` will not be enough

Comment: You could declare the `std::string` `sName` before the call to `gcm_decrypt` and make it big enough to fit whatever the function needs to put in it - and use `sName.data()` instead pf `plaintext`.  Afterwards, `resize()` it to the actual number of `char`s that was put in it.

Answer (score 0):

Following @drescherjm advice, i updated it to:

The end code is

```
int main(void)
{
    std::string key_encoded = "DgvkCrkyBNSy9yHP1Yznyc2DkHTIUXaO6NlEw4CSq0E=";
    std::string decoded_key = base64_decode(key_encoded);

    std::string token_encoded = "rj_ZkkZUOZMxZOfOmLpEUB3siU7u6RjZFeM9s-gb_xCR56WFKFAJiMyF2T6CBRmlh_Sy0i_lfyT9AI8sEif8MTIIszyzSl_aDnG48aO50yaHGuRSYbUbSYm9WIiQ0g==";
    std::string token_decoded_tmp = base64_decode( token_encoded );
    std::string token_decoded( token_decoded_tmp.begin()+32, token_decoded_tmp.end() );
    int ciphertext_len = token_decoded.size();

    std::string aad = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    int aad_len = aad.size();

    std::string tag( token_decoded_tmp.begin()+16, token_decoded_tmp.end()+32 );
    std::string iv( token_decoded_tmp.begin(), token_decoded_tmp.begin()+16 );
    int iv_len = iv.size();

    int ret = 0;
    unsigned char plaintext[1024];
    ret = gcm_decrypt( 
        (unsigned char*)token_decoded.c_str(),
        ciphertext_len, 
        (unsigned char*)aad.c_str(), 
        aad_len, 
        (unsigned char*)tag.c_str(),
        (unsigned char*)decoded_key.c_str(), 
        (unsigned char*)iv.c_str(), 
        iv_len, 
        plaintext 
    );
    cout << "ret: " << ret << endl;
    cout << "plaintext: <" << plaintext << ">" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And it's perfect now. Thanks!

@drescherjm i can't mark your answer as the right one.

Comment: `&ciphertext[0]` should be `ciphertext`

Comment: `&aad[0]` I hope you did not do the same mistake with this and others as you did with `ciphertext`

Comment: I think `ciphertext_len` needs to be 1024 since that is the number of items in the array.